# I'm making a code that keeps asking the user to input a number until that number is a negative one using While

Tags: c#, while-loop, new-operator

```
    using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
   
   int n1;

   while (n1 <= 0) {
     n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }
   }
  }
```

the Console keeps saying "use of unassigned local variable" and when i try it with 'do While' it just doesn't repeat the code inside. I'm really new to coding and i would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You should initialize n1 before you test its value in while loop `int n1=0`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int n1;
```

To

```
int n1 = 0;
```

The compiler is complaining because you didn't give n1 a value before you used it in the while loop. Making it zero (or less) ensures the while loop will run to ask the user

At some point you might want to ask the user for another number. Rather than repeat this code, make a method out of it. Make the method return an int and take a string question to print out so you can vary what you ask. Have the while loop print the question and then read the answer. Consider also using int.TryParse so that if the user enters non numbers it doesn't crash the program

Final point, your question title says "keep asking until the user enters a negative number" but `while(n1<=0)` doesn't do this, it does the opposite and will "keep asking *while* the user enters **negative** numbers" (i.e. "*until* the user enters a **positive** number")

Comment: Added some stuff for clarification, feel free to revert if you feel it doesn't add much